# Customize web api help page to remove the request formats

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my web api application I am accepting Application/Json mediatype as request. So I would want to customize the help page to remove the other formats such as  application/xml, text/xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded etc. Any help is really appreciable.

Answer (score 5):

As per [JSON and XML Serialization in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#removing_the_json_or_xml_formatter) the way to this is to call this from your Application_Start method, defined in Global.asax.

```
void ConfigureApi(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Remove the JSON formatter
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);

    // or

    // Remove the XML formatter
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into you help page area and find HelpPageApiModel.cshtml in DisplayTemplates

and remove this lines given below or you can comment it may you need it sometime.

```
@if (Model.SampleRequests.Count > 0)
{
    <h3>Request Formats</h3>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SampleRequests, "Samples")
}
```